Understanding partial derivative error in Dymos
I've built a dynamics model in Dymos, using Jax to calculate the partial derivatives using auto-differentiation. The code looks something like the following:
import openmdao.api as om
import dymos as dm
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

# Define dynamics
class Dynamics(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self._compute_primal_vec = jax.vmap(self._compute_primal)
        self._compute_partials_vec = jax.jit(jax.vmap(jax.jacfwd(self._compute_primal, argnums=np.arange(5))))

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('num_nodes', types=int)

    def setup(self):
        nn = self.options['num_nodes']

        # States
        self.add_input('theta', shape=(nn,), desc='orientation, anticlockwise from positive x', units='rad')
        self.add_input('omega', shape=(nn,), desc='angular velocity, positive anticlockwise', units='rad/s')
        
        # Controls
        self.add_input('rho', shape=(nn,), desc='rotational control input')

        # Parameters
        self.add_input('k', shape=(nn,), desc='rotational resistance coefficient')
        self.add_input('I', shape=(nn,), desc='rotational moment of inertia', units='kg*m**2')

        # Outputs
        self.add_output('omega_dot', val=np.zeros(nn), desc='rate of change of angular velocity', units='rad/s**2')

        # Partials declared analytically
        arange = np.arange(nn)
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='exact', rows=arange, cols=arange)

    # Dynamics go here
    @partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(0,))
    def _compute_primal(self, theta, omega, rho, k, I):
        # For some reason, need to assign these otherwise they have the value 0/0J when checking the partials.
        I = 1
        k = 1

        # Calculate moments
        tau = rho - k*omega**2 # Rotational torque

        # Calculate state rates of change (dynamics)
        # Rotational
        omega_dot = tau / I

        return omega_dot
    
    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        omega_dot = self._compute_primal_vec(*inputs.values())

        if np.isnan(np.sum(omega_dot)):
            raise Exception("NaN values found in rates")
        
        outputs['omega_dot'] = omega_dot

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        output_names = ['omega_dot']
        input_names = ['theta', 'omega', 'rho', 'k', 'I']

        computed_partials = self._compute_partials_vec(*inputs.values())

        # Cycle through computed partials
        for out_ind, output_name in enumerate(output_names):
            for in_ind, input_name in enumerate(input_names):
                partials[output_name, input_name] = computed_partials[out_ind][in_ind]

This code may look a bit strange because it's been cut down from a larger dynamics model, but it effectively models the rotation of an object with moment of inertia I given a torque input tau, which is a function of a control input rho. Theta is the orientation, and omega the angular velocity.
What might be slightly strange about the way I've built this too is the use of Jax to try to calculate the partial derivatives automatically. I've seen this done in the OpenMDAO and Dymos examples, e.g. using wrap_ode (OpenMDAO example, Dymos wrap_ode example), but my approach is slightly different, so I don't know if it plays any part in the strange behaviour I'm experiencing.
The problem is built and set up as follows (initial state, control and parameter values aren't set as I'm only interested in checking the partial derivatives):
num_segments = 10
order = 3

# Build problem
prob = om.Problem()
traj = dm.Trajectory()
prob.model.add_subsystem('traj', traj)
phase = dm.Phase(ode_class=Dynamics, transcription=dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=num_segments, order=order),
                 ode_init_kwargs={})
traj.add_phase('phase0', phase)

# Add states, controls, parameters and objective
# States
phase.add_state('theta', rate_source='omega', targets=['theta'], units='rad')
phase.add_state('omega', rate_source='omega_dot', targets=['omega'], units='rad/s')
# Controls
phase.add_control('rho', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True, targets=['rho'])
# Parameters
phase.add_parameter('k', targets=['k'])
phase.add_parameter('I', units='kg*m**2', targets=['I'])

# Configure and set up
prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

When I run check_partials using prob.check_partials(method='cs', compact_print=True), I get some significant, and systematic-looking, errors:

Stranger still, I don't get an error for omega_dot w.r.t theta, which has an absolute error of 9.5238e-01 and a relative error of 1.0000e+00 in the full model.
What could be causing this? Is it an issue with the model itself, or perhaps the way I'm using Jax? There are a few peculiarities:

The fact that the errors are for different partials in the original model and this minimum working example.
In _compute_primal(...), the values of k and I don't 'carry through' into the function - they end up being 0 or 0J when check_partials is run (which is why I have to set them explicitly in _compute_primal, to avoid division by zero errors) - why would this be?

As an extra aside, I'm not sure what the difference is between the rhs_disc and rhs_col components of the phase?
Many thanks, I really appreciate any assistance.

Here are more details for the non-zero/non-nan partials (these were screenshotted on a different run, and it seems to have changed in-between):





Edit
Because the MWE has only one return value from _compute_primal, it doesn't work in the same way. Here is the full code:
# Define dynamics
class BoatDynamicsJax(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self._compute_primal_vec = jax.vmap(self._compute_primal)
        self._compute_partials_vec = jax.jit(jax.vmap(jax.jacfwd(self._compute_primal, argnums=np.arange(13))))

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('num_nodes', types=int)
        self.options.declare('flow_velocity')

    def setup(self):
        nn = self.options['num_nodes']

        # States
        self.add_input('x', shape=(nn,), desc='x displacement', units='m')
        self.add_input('y', shape=(nn,), desc='y displacement', units='m')
        self.add_input('u', shape=(nn,), desc='x velocity', units='m/s')
        self.add_input('v', shape=(nn,), desc='y velocity', units='m/s')
        self.add_input('theta', shape=(nn,), desc='heading angle, anticlockwise from positive x', units='rad')
        self.add_input('omega', shape=(nn,), desc='angular velocity, positive anticlockwise', units='rad/s')
        
        # Controls
        self.add_input('rho', shape=(nn,), desc='rotational control input')
        self.add_input('t', shape=(nn,), desc='propulsive throttle force, in ib direction', units='N')

        # Parameters
        self.add_input('m', shape=(nn,), desc='mass', units='kg')
        self.add_input('Cdl', shape=(nn,), desc='longitudinal drag coefficient')
        self.add_input('Cds', shape=(nn,), desc='lateral (sideways) drag coefficient')
        self.add_input('k', shape=(nn,), desc='rotational drag coefficient')
        self.add_input('I', shape=(nn,), desc='rotational moment of inertia', units='kg*m**2')

        # x_dot, y_dot and theta_dot are u, v and omega respectively, so we don't need to calculate outputs for them.
        self.add_output('u_dot', val=np.zeros(nn), desc='rate of change of u velocity', units='m/s**2')
        self.add_output('v_dot', val=np.zeros(nn), desc='rate of change of y velocity', units='m/s**2')
        self.add_output('omega_dot', val=np.zeros(nn), desc='rate of change of angular velocity', units='rad/s**2')

        # Not used, but for logging.
        self.add_output('Fdi', np.zeros(nn), desc='longitudinal drag force, aligned with ib', units='N')
        self.add_output('Fdj', np.zeros(nn), desc='lateral drag force, aligned with jb', units='N')

        # Partials declared analytically
        arange = np.arange(nn)
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='exact', rows=arange, cols=arange)

    # Dynamics go here
    @partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(0,))
    def _compute_primal(self, x, y, u, v, theta, omega, rho, t, m, Cdl, Cds, k, I):
        # Define body frame basis vectors
        ib = jnp.array([jnp.cos(theta), jnp.sin(theta)])
        jb = jnp.array([-jnp.sin(theta), jnp.cos(theta)])

        # Calculate flow-relative velocity vector, v_r.
        v_f = self.options['flow_velocity'](x, y)   # Flow velocity vector
        v_vec = jnp.array([u, v])                   # Inertial velocity vector
        v_r = v_vec - v_f                           # Relative velocity vector

        # Get body-axis velocities
        vi = jnp.dot(v_r, ib)
        vj = jnp.dot(v_r, jb)

        # Calculate forces and moments
        Fdi = -Cdl*vi   # Drag force in ib direction
        Fdj = -Cds*vj   # Drag force in jb direction
        Fi = Fdi + t    # Sum of forces in ib direction
        Fj = Fdj        # Sum of forces in jb direction
        tau = rho*vi - k*omega # Rotational torque

        # Calculate state rates of change (dynamics)
        # Linear
        v_vec_dot = (1/m)*(Fi*ib + Fj*jb)
        u_dot, v_dot = v_vec_dot
        # Rotational
        omega_dot = tau / I

        return u_dot, v_dot, omega_dot, Fdi, Fdj
    
    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        # print("Running compute")
        rates = np.array(self._compute_primal_vec(*inputs.values()))
        
        # Check for nan values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736590/fast-check-for-nan-in-numpy
        if np.isnan(np.sum(rates)):
            raise Exception("NaN values found in rates")
        
        u_dot, v_dot, omega_dot, Fdi, Fdj = rates

        outputs['u_dot'] = u_dot
        outputs['v_dot'] = v_dot
        outputs['omega_dot'] = omega_dot
        outputs['Fdi'] = Fdi
        outputs['Fdj'] = Fdj

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        output_names = ['u_dot', 'v_dot', 'omega_dot', 'Fdi', 'Fdj']
        input_names = ['x', 'y', 'u', 'v', 'theta', 'omega', 'rho', 't', 'm', 'Cdl', 'Cds', 'k', 'I']

        computed_partials = self._compute_partials_vec(*inputs.values())

        # Cycle through computed partials
        for out_ind, output_name in enumerate(output_names):
            for in_ind, input_name in enumerate(input_names):
                partials[output_name, input_name] = computed_partials[out_ind][in_ind]

# Setup Dymos/OpenMDAO problem
# =================================
# Options
num_segments = 10
order = 3

flow = lambda x, y: jnp.array([0., -x])

# =================================
# OpenMDAO Problem
prob = om.Problem()

traj = dm.Trajectory()
# Trajectory gets added to the problem
prob.model.add_subsystem('traj', traj)

phase = dm.Phase(ode_class=BoatDynamicsJax, transcription=dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=num_segments, order=order),
                 ode_init_kwargs={'flow_velocity': flow})
traj.add_phase('phase0', phase)

# =================================
# Add states, controls, parameters and objective

# States
phase.add_state('x', rate_source='u', targets=['x'], units='m')
phase.add_state('y', rate_source='v', targets=['y'], units='m')
phase.add_state('u', rate_source='u_dot', targets=['u'], units='m/s')
phase.add_state('v', rate_source='v_dot', targets=['v'], units='m/s')
phase.add_state('theta', rate_source='omega', targets=['theta'], units='rad')
phase.add_state('omega', rate_source='omega_dot', targets=['omega'], units='rad/s')

# Controls
phase.add_control('rho', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True, targets=['rho'])
phase.add_control('t', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True, targets=['t'])

# Parameters
phase.add_parameter('m', units='kg', targets=['m'])
phase.add_parameter('Cdl', targets=['Cdl'])
phase.add_parameter('Cds', targets=['Cds'])
phase.add_parameter('k', targets=['k'])
phase.add_parameter('I', units='kg*m**2', targets=['I'])

# Log forces, for plotting.
phase.add_timeseries_output('Fdi')
phase.add_timeseries_output('Fdj')

phase.set_time_options(fix_initial=True, duration_bounds=(5, 200.0))
phase.add_objective('time', loc='final')

# Set up constraints
traj.link_phases(['phase0', 'phase0'], ['x', 'theta'])
phase.add_path_constraint('t', lower=0)

# =================================
# Configure

# Set IPOPT as optimiser
prob.driver = om.pyOptSparseDriver(optimizer='IPOPT')
prob.driver.opt_settings['print_level'] = 5
prob.driver.declare_coloring()

prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

# =================================
# Set initial state, control and parameter values

# Time
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.t_initial', 0.0)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.t_duration', 30.0)

# States
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:x', -2.)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:y', 0.)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:u', 5.)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:v', 0.)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:theta', 0.)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:omega', 0.)

# Controls
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.controls:rho', -0.1)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.controls:t', 0.)

# Parameters
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:m', 1.)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:Cdl', 0.05)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:Cds', 0.2)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:k', 0.5)
prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:I', 1.)

# =================================
# Run simulation

prob.run_model()

prob.check_partials(method='cs', compact_print=True)

I get the same thing - lots of errors which are greater than the tolerance:

Interestingly, the errors are much smaller using forward difference:

So maybe the computed partials for checking are wrong, because Jax isn't compatible with complex numbers?

There are a couple of issues here.
First
In compute_partials, the value returned by jax and stored in computed_partials is just a 1D sequence in this case, so when you do this:
partials[output_name, input_name] = computed_partials[out_ind][in_ind]

It's always pulling out a single index associated with the partial wrt to the first input (theta), which in this case is zero.
The crux of your issue is fixed by doing this:
partials[output_name, input_name] = computed_partials[in_ind]

(Side note, theres no need to make this ODE a function of theta so you can avoid some computational overhead by removing it.)
Second
Don't override the values of inputs for k and I in compute_primal.
Dymos is setting the default values of the controls and parameters to zero. In general, before you run compute partials, it's a good idea to set the values to some non-default.
    # Configure and set up
    prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.t_initial', 0.0)
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.t_duration', 1.0)
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:theta', phase.interp('theta', [0, 1.0]))
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:omega', phase.interp('omega', [1.0, 0.0]))
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.controls:rho', phase.interp('rho', [0.5, 0.7]))
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.states:omega', phase.interp('omega', [1.0, 0.0]))
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:k', 0.8)
    prob.set_val('traj.phase0.parameters:I', 0.9)

    prob.run_model()

    prob.check_partials(method='cs', compact_print=True)

Note that the development version of dymos has better API for doing this interpolation across the dynamic variables (the states and controls). This should be released in the next few weeks. This will allow users to more easily swap out transcriptions.
Edited Answer for full model
When your check mag shows up as 0 like this, it strongly suggests that your model is not compatible with complex numbers.
To my knowledge, jax is for the most part, as complex step was working with the simpler model.
In this case, I'm going to wager that the culprit is this line:
v_vec = jnp.array([u, v])

Here you're allocating a non-complex array, so complex step isn't propagating through anything that depends upon it.
Fortunately, OpenMDAO components can detect if they're being run under complex step using the self.under_complex_step flag.
If you add the logic to allocate that array as either real or complex, depending on the value of the flag, your complex-step should function correctly.

Hi Rob, many thanks for your answer. The second bit fixed my problem with check_partials - I did set some initial values, but hadn't called run_model before the partials check, which seems to have been the cause of the issue. For the first part, my MWE was probably too simple, as it's not just a 1D sequence in the full model but I'm still having problems. I'll edit the question to include the full dynamics model. Thanks again for your assistance.

The derivative system in OpenMDAO relies on the residuals of all implicit calcs being zero (or close to it), which means calling run_model first. Check partials could do a "run_model" itself, but in some cases doing it twice could be quite expensive, like when REALLY expensive models are involved.

@LordCat I've edited the answer.  In this case you're allocating an array and I suspect it's discarding the complex information.  At any rate, something is not compatible with complex step in that compute method since using finite difference doesn't seem to have an issue.
